# R markdown error: knit to pdf, version of "xfun"

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, citrix

The knit process to PDF stopped with the following message

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'xfun' 0.22 is already loaded, but >= 0.29 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
```

The installed version of *xfun* is

```
packageVersion("xfun")
[1] ‘0.22’
```

That's why I updated this package with

```
install.packages("xfun", dependencies = TRUE)


Installing package into ‘.../R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
versuche URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/xfun_0.30.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 399716 bytes (390 KB)
downloaded 390 KB

package ‘xfun’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\...\Temp\20\RtmpYB5uib\downloaded_packages
```

After that the version of *xfun* is

```
packageVersion("xfun")
[1] ‘0.30’
```

But the error message of the knit process remains the same

```
namespace 'xfun' 0.22 is already loaded, but >= 0.29 is required
```

The R version is

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.5                         
year           2021                        
month          03                          
day            31                          
svn rev        80133                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
nickname       Shake and Throw
```

The system is a Citrix desktop with Windows

```
benchmarkme::get_sys_details()

Loading required package: benchmarkme
$sys_info
$sys_info$sysname
[1] "Windows"

$sys_info$release
[1] "Server x64"

$sys_info$version
[1] "build 14393"

$sys_info$machine
[1] "x86-64"


$platform_info
$platform_info$OS.type
[1] "windows"

$platform_info$file.sep
[1] "/"

$platform_info$dynlib.ext
[1] ".dll"

$platform_info$GUI
[1] "RStudio"

$platform_info$endian
[1] "little"

$platform_info$pkgType
[1] "win.binary"

$platform_info$path.sep
[1] ";"

$platform_info$r_arch
[1] "x64"


$r_version
$r_version$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$r_version$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$r_version$os
[1] "mingw32"

$r_version$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"

$r_version$status
[1] ""

$r_version$major
[1] "4"

$r_version$minor
[1] "0.5"

$r_version$year
[1] "2021"

$r_version$month
[1] "03"

$r_version$day
[1] "31"

$r_version$`svn rev`
[1] "80133"

$r_version$language
[1] "R"

$r_version$version.string
[1] "R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)"

$r_version$nickname
[1] "Shake and Throw"


$ram
256GB

$cpu
$cpu$vendor_id
[1] "AuthenticAMD"

$cpu$model_name
[1] "AMD EPYC 7542 32-Core Processor"

$cpu$no_of_cores
[1] 12
```

Can anyone help?
Has anyone experience with R in a Citrix environment?